# Tool for exploring Windows Vista Audio device chain (tree?)

Tags: windows-vista, audio

The new Vista Audio subsystem is set up to be a chain of devices starting with the inputs, going through all the various controls (like mixers and volumen controls) and then ending up at various endpoints (like speakers or headphones).

My question is: Is there a tool out there that will show all the endpoints devices in the system, and what devices are chained together?  Ideally, it would diagram the topology, showing what inputs where connected to what outputs, and you would be able to see all the properties for each part of the audio system.

Comment: One day -- if i get ambitious I guess I will try and write one.

Answer (score 4):

Larry Osterman (one of the Vista Audio developers) has a great [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/) with many posts about [Vista Audio](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/tags/Audio/default.aspx).  Some potentially helpful helpful posts:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/13/428724.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/14/428962.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/09/21/472480.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/09/23/473351.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2007/03/06/how-do-i-change-the-master-volume-in-windows-vista.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2007/10/31/what-happens-when-audio-rendering-fails.aspx

Also:

- [Enumerating Audio Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678716(VS.85).aspx)
- [Audio Endpoints in Vista](http://ampalliance.org/files/folders/53/download.aspx) (PPT)

I thought I remembered him having some sample code for doing exactly what you describe, but I'm probably remembering wrong as I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the [IDeviceTopology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371376(VS.85).aspx) API which was designed for exactly your problem.