# Recording sound sent to speakers

Tags: java, c++, windows, audio

I'm trying to make a program which allows me to capture every sound which I can hear through my speakers. I don't have any idea how I can do this... I want to send it to another PC using sockets (how can I do this?). I want to write it in Java or C++ (I definitely prefer Java) on Windows.

Edit 
Inshort, I want to send & receive Audio input using Java

Please help,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 7 you can do this using WASAPI (see [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808287/windows-vista-7-how-to-sample-output-audio-mix/5808780#5808780)). In order to use WASAPI I would recommend to use either C++ or some .net based language (C#, vb.net, etc)
For other versions of Windows, you will need an intermediate virtual sound card, and you will only be able to capure the audio streams that go through this virtual driver. There is a commercial option [here](http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm),but I am sure there are others.

One more [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798200/java-record-mic-to-byte-array-and-play-sound)